# SQL Query to LINQ for MVC Controller

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to convert he following SQL statement to LINQ to use in an MVC Controller.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS LoginCount, InsertDate, CertificateNumber
FROM dbo.LogIns
GROUP BY InsertDate, CertificateNumber
```

I have made several attempts with no luck.

Comment: Could you show us an attempt where you got furthest in your opinion? Otherwise this question seems to be, can you do it for me.

Comment: I have been trying to resolve this since yesterday. My brain is fried and my attempts are no longer in ctrl z or ctrl y. Next time I shall save all my attempts as there seems to be people that would say do it for me here but I am not one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = db.LogIns.GroupBy(x => new { x.InsertDate, x.CertificateNumber })
                      .Select(x => new 
                             { 
                                   InsertDate = x.Key.InsertDate,
                                   CertificateNumber = x.Key.CertificateNumber,
                                   LoginCount = x.Count() 
                              });
```

Or with query syntax:-

```
var result = from x in db.LogIns
             group x by new { x.InsertDate, x.CertificateNumber } into g
             select new 
             {
                 InsertDate = g.Key.InsertDate,
                 CertificateNumber = g.Key.CertificateNumber,
                 LoginCount = g.Count() 
             };
```

Comment: Thanks Getting 'object' does not contain a definition for 'InsertDate' from the view. I am passing the results via a ViewBag.

Comment: Why? You don't have `InsertDate` property in LogIns type?

Comment: Thought I Did    'public partial class LogIn
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> InsertDate { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public string CertificateNumber { get; set; }
    }'

Comment: Okay, Just read your comment properly, since you are passing it via `ViewBag`, you can't access it directly. You need to type-cast it like this:- `IEnumerable<LogIn> LogIns = (IEnumerable<LogIn)ViewBag.LogIn;`

Comment: I appreciate your help and excuse my ignorance but am getting lost. I am attempting to return the results of the query to a list in the view. Where does the line above go, I tried it in the controller and the view.

Comment: It would be better if you query it in Controller (where you'll have access to data source as well) and pass it to view as strongly typed and not view `ViewBag`(if possible)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73667/discussion-between-doug-farrell-and-rahul-singh).